# C# access to TreeNode parameter

Tags: c#

Here is code:

```
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{

    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name + " (" + DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(directoryInfo.FullName)) + " bytes)" + " (" + directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos().Length + " files)"+ directoryInfo.CreationTime); 


   foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())    
       directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

   foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
       directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name + " (" + file.Length + " bytes)"));
    return directoryNode;
}
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNodeText = "a";
    textBox1.Text = selectedNodeText;
}
```

I need to access directoryInfo.CreationTime from TreeNode and display it in treeView1_AfterSelect text.Box1 but I can't find right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx) to put the value there and then access it in the event :

```
directoryNode.Tag = directoryInfo;
```

and then in event you can access it :

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    var directoryInfo = e.Node.Tag as DirectoryInfo;
    var time = directoryinfo.CreationTime;
}
```

or:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

    var directoryInfo = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as DirectoryInfo;
    var creationTime = drInfo.CreationTime;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: glad it helped (Y)

Comment: It works great with directories, but if I click on file in treeView it crashs.

Comment: Issue occurs at: var creationTime = directoryInfo.CreationTime; 

Exception: 'System.NullReferenceException' in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") System.NullReferenceException

Comment: that means directoryInfo is null

Comment: I know, but don't know to fix.

Comment: debug the code portion where you are setting `Tag` for each node, it must be wrong something there

Answer (score 1):

Tree nodes expose the `Tag` property that is used to store and retrieve a custom information under nodes. It can even hold a reference to a complex structure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx